# CloudFormation Change Set Showing Replacement Despite no change

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

A resource of type AWS::RDS::DBInstance has already been deployed. Even though I didn't specify it in the template, the database is automatically using the standard port 3306. That is good and expected.

However, now I want to *explicitly* specify the port number in the template, by adding [that property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-port): `Port: "3306"`.

The problem is that, when I add that to the template, the CloudFormation change set tells me that this is a modification that will cause a *replacement* of the database. Here's the Change Set:

```
[
  {
    "resourceChange": {
      "logicalResourceId": "RDSDBInstanceA",
      "action": "Modify",
      "physicalResourceId": "awesome-db",
      "resourceType": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "replacement": "True",
      "moduleInfo": null,
      "details": [
        {
          "target": {
            "name": "Port",
            "requiresRecreation": "Always",
            "attribute": "Properties"
          },
          "causingEntity": null,
          "evaluation": "Static",
          "changeSource": "DirectModification"
        }
      ],
      "changeSetId": null,
      "scope": [
        "Properties"
      ]
    },
    "hookInvocationCount": null,
    "type": "Resource"
  }
]
```

***Expected Behavior***

I expect CloudFormation to say: no changes detected. Because the database is already using port 3306, so *effectively* there is no change.

***Why am I trying to figure this out, if it's already using the port I want?***

So that I can re-use my MySQL template for Postgres, conditionally changing the port number to the standard 5432. Oddly enough, when I deployed a Postgres database without specifying the port number, it used 3306 -- that's a problem for me, since I want the standard port 5432.

***Things I've tried:***

- tricking CloudFormation into thinking there's no change, by using `AWS::NoValue` as the value for the `Port` property when it's a MySQL deployment:

```
Port: !If [IsMySQL, AWS::NoValue, "5432"]
```

That had the same result.

***If this were Terraform...***

It would check the state, see that the port is already 3306, and say, "no change".

***My Question***

How do I avoid replacement of the database while still adding this property to the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFormation doesn't look at the deployed resources to identify change, it simply compares the currently deploy stack to the new stack. So, in this case, you have a stack that previously didn't include a value and now is including it, which CF considers a change. I am a little surprised that the `AWS::NoValue` option didn't work.

One option for addressing this is to take advantage of stack imports. The steps would be something like this:

1. Update the current stack by setting the `DeletionPolicy` to `RETAIN` for the current RDS instance (if it isn't already).
2. Update the current stack, removing the RDS instance. The RDS instance will still be there, but it won't be controlled by CF anymore.
3. Add the RDS back into your template, configured the way you want it, and use the "Import resources into stack" option in CF. This should allow you to add the RDS instance back into your stack, configured the way you want it.

Keep in mind that when you import something into a stack CF just assumes the configuration in the template matches the imported resource.